# pickadate.js set focus depending on first input

Tags: javascript, jquery, date, pickadate

I am using pickadate.js for arrival & departure dates and would like the departure date to disallow any date on or before the arrival date and set the departure date to focus on the date after the arrival date. Thus an arrival on, say, 16th December 2016 would permit a departure date only from 17th Dec to be selected. This is what I have:

```
        <script src="pickadate/lib/jquery.js"></script>
        <script src="pickadate/lib/picker.js"></script>
        <script src="pickadate/lib/picker.date.js"></script>
        <script src="pickadate/lib/legacy.js"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript">
            $('#dateArrival').pickadate({
                min: true,
                max: new Date(2018,12,31),
                format: 'd mmm yyyy',   // Friendly format displayed to user
                formatSubmit: 'yyyy-mm-dd', // Actual format used by application
                hiddenName: true,           // Allows two different formats
                disable: [ // Dates already booked
                new Date(2016,11,13),
                new Date(2016,11,29)
                ]
            });

            $('#dateDepart').pickadate({
                min: true,
                max: new Date(2018,12,31),
                format: 'd mmm yyyy',
                formatSubmit: 'yyyy-mm-dd',
                hiddenName: true,
                disable: [
                new Date(2016,11,13),
                new Date(2016,11,29)
                ]
            });
        </script>
```

Answer (score 2):

```
var frompic = $('#input_from').pickadate();
var topic   = $('#input_to').pickadate();
```

After initialization , retrieve picker objects

```
fromIns = frompic.pickadate('picker');
toIns   = topic.pickadate('picker');
```

Add `set` event handler

```
fromIns.on('set', function(event) {
  if ( event.select ) {
    sel =  fromIns.get('select'); //get entered date
    newDte = new Date( sel.year,sel.month,sel.date ) ;
    newDte.setDate(newDte.getDate()+1); // inc date by 1
    toIns.set('min', new Date( newDte.getFullYear(),newDte.getMonth(),newDte.getDate()));
 }
});
```